# Laravel: How do I move my images to s3 in production and in development let it stay locally?

Tags: laravel

I have read [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-use-local-filesystem-for-development-but-s3-for-production), however I'm still not really sure how to handle this.

Of course, I could set `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` to `s3`, but this won't really work.

Let me explain:

If we upload a simple avatar file:

```
request()
        ->file('avatar')
        ->store('avatars', 'public')
```

The file is saved in the DB for example: `avatars/R6ZGC9U0c22mKMcAADZbc8kJeU8soTvOuNFvnYgv.jpeg`

This file is stored in the local public storage file. However, if we now want to change the default filesystem to S3, nothing is going to change obviously, because I stated to save it to public.

Now, this is going to be even harder, when we fetch the image via the `asset`method. Usually, I just need to write:

```
 public function getAvatarAttribute($avatar)
{
    return asset('storage/' . $avatar));
}
```

to get the avatar file (because of the symlink in the public folder).

What now? I obviously don't save a storage folder.

How would you handle this?

Comment: First solution maybe: https://laravel-news.com/minio-s3-compliant-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I believe this to be a flaw in some of Laravel’s abstraction layers; some drivers require you to do something entirely differently, and I agree that this does not make sense.

I just created an s3 bucket for local testing/development too.  This has the benefit that you develop/test as it will be running on production too.

Comment: For future readers, in Digital Ocean you can create unlimited "Spaces" for the 5€. So now you can do it as @David says, create new buckets aka Spaces for testing etc.